# Oracle SQL Query was running fine earlier but now takes long time without executing

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to execute this Oracle query which is taking a long time without getting executing,but when I ran this query last week it took approx 30 min to execute. The query looks absolutely fine to me, not sure what the problem is.
Kindly assist.

```
select (select current_date from dual) as CURR_DATE, 
       dealer_code dealer, 
       trunc(transmit_ts) transmit_date, 
       count(*) records
from DEALER_PART_INVENTORY_VW 
where trunc(TRANSMIT_TS) between '01-Jan-14' and current_date
group by dealer_code, trunc(transmit_ts)
order by 1 asc, 2 asc, trunc(transmit_ts) desc
```

Comment: So it used to execute much faster? Much more data, since between '01-Jan-14' and current_date increases every single day? Database statistics?

Comment: Presumably, the `_VW` means that the `from` clause is referring to a view.  That is probably where the problem lies.

Comment: post the explain plan

Comment: I understand that the data is huge but it ran within 30 min this Monday and how can it become so slow. I ran the query this afternoon 1 pm and it is still running..
yes _VW is referring to the view

Comment: Post the explain plan, please.

Answer (score 0):

If it is not executing at all, it may be that there is a lock on the table from an open transaction.

Make sure all transactions are closed and try it again.

Also, I would suggest updating statistics on the database if the query is taking 30 minutes on a good run.